# Attribute routing MVC5 route prefix with template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

Is it possible to have route prefix with template? I need to specify route/route prefix on my base controller so every controller/action would allow prefixing url with language slug.

```
www.mydomain.com/en/Search
www.mydomain.com/da/Sogning
www.mydomain.com/Hledat
```

These three routes would lead to the same action.

I would like something like this

```
[RoutePrefix("{language?}")]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that be better on the Route template?

```
[Route("{language?}/{action=index}/{id?}")]
```

Comment: This will not work, because when you add route attribute on action it overrides the route attribute from controller